# Mutating function inside class

Tags: swift, function, class

Consider this class in Swift:

```
class Zombie: Monster {
    var walksWithLimp = true

    final override func terrorizeTown()
    {
        town?.changePopulation(-10)
        super.terrorizeTown()
    }

    func changeName(name: String, walksWithLimp: Bool)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.walksWithLimp = walksWithLimp
    }
}
```

Zombie inherits the name field from the Monster class.

```
var name = "Monster"
```

Why does

```
fredTheZombie.changeName("Tom", walksWithLimp: true)
```

work even if there is no mutating keyword before the function header?

Comment: A `class` is a reference type in Swift. Hence, mutating the _class instance_ `fredTheZombie` would mean mutating its actual reference. Mutating it's wrapped members, on the other hand, is not considered as mutating the class instance itself; hence no need for the `mutating` keyword for such cases.

Comment: I've read that in order to change a value of a variable in a class (inside an instance method) you have to declare the function mutating. I haven't done that...

Comment: That is a rule that holds for mutating the members of _value types_ (e.g. the member properties of a `struct`). Mutating a member of a value type means mutating the value type itself (`self`), whereas mutating a member of a reference type will not mean the reference of the reference type (which is considered `self`) is mutated.

Comment: Happy to help. For additional details, see Subsection _Modifying Value Types from Within Instance Methods_ in [The Language Guide - Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [The Language Guide - Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html):

> **Modifying Value Types from Within Instance Methods**
>
> Structures and enumerations are *value* types. By default, the
>   properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance
>   methods.
>
> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or
>   enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating
>   behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change)
>   its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes
>   are written back to the original structure when the method ends. The
>   method can also assign a completely new instance to its implicit `self`
>   property, and this new instance will replace the existing one when the
>   method ends.
>
> You can opt in to this behavior by placing the `mutating` keyword before
>   the func keyword for that method ...

Hence, we need to include the keyword `mutating` to allow a member (e.g. a function<sup>†</sup>) of a *value* type to mutate its members (e.g. the member properties of a `struct`). Mutating a member of a value type instance means mutating the value type instance itself (`self`), whereas mutating a member of a *reference* type instance will not mean the reference of the reference type instance (which is considered `self`) is mutated.

Hence, since a `class` is a reference type in Swift, we need not include the `mutating` keyword in any of the instance methods of your `Zombie` class, even if they mutate the instance members or the class. If we were to speak of mutating the actual class instance `fredTheZombie`, we would refer to mutating its actual *reference* (e.g. to point at another `Zombie` instance).

<sub>[†]: As another example, we may use e.g. `mutating` getters (`get`); in which case we need to mark this explicitly as these are `nonmutating` by default. Setters (`set`), on the other hand, are `mutating` by default, and hence need no `mutating` keyword even if they mutate members of a value type.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

`mutating` is not relevant for classes, it is only for value types, such as `struct` and `enum`

Answer (score 3):

Without mutating func

```
struct Counter {
    let count: Int

    init(count: Int = 0) {
        self.count = count
    }

    // the functional approach
    func counterByIncrementing() -> Counter {
        let newCount = count + 1
        return Counter(count: newCount)
    }
}

var counter = Counter()
counter = counter.counterByIncrementing()
```

Mutating func

```
struct Counter {
    // this now has to be a var :/
    var count: Int

    init(count: Int = 0) {
        self.count = count
    }

    // the mutating keyword approach
    mutating func increment() {
        count += 1
    }
}

var counter = Counter()
counter.increment()
```

In class, all func are mutating. But for struct and enum we need to specify.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy to understand example, verified in **Swift 3 & 4**

```
struct City
{
  var population : Int 

  func changePopulation(newpopulation : Int) {
     population = newpopulation //error: cannot modify property "population"
  }
}

  var mycity = City(population : 500)
  mycity.changePopulation(newpopulation : 2000) //error: cannot modify property "population"
```

***Solution***

```
mutating func changePopulation(newpopulation : Int)
```