# What is the more accurate difference between function overriding and function mutating? In swift particularly

Tags: swift, generics, overriding, mutating-function

Essentially both are used to modify behaviour of a function to our custom needs. But why the necessity arise to have two ways to do the same thing when both are used for same purpose.

I'm assuming, if a function has **HEAD** which takes ***parameters*** and a **BODY** which has a certain ***functionality*** with those parameters

**Mutating** function is used when we have to modify at the **HEAD**.

**Mutating** -> **HEAD** -> ***parameters*** and

**Overriding** function is used when we have to modify at the **BODY**

**Overriding** -> **BODY** -> ***functionality***

I've searched over the internet..but found no satisfactory explanation anywhere. Please help me understand them better. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'd say your idea of what mutating means is the source of the difficulty. It seems to be greatly at variance with reality. See the second section of https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html

Comment: Can you show some code to illustrate your understanding of mutating functions (show how it modifies the parameters)? I think what you understand as a "mutating function" might be different from what the wider community understand as a "mutating function".

Comment: I think a careful reading of the Swift Language Guide will answer this. In essence, all the assumptions expressed in the post are just wrong. There's nothing to do with "modify behaviour", "mutating the parameters" or anything to do with a "head" or "body" (whatever those are even trying to refer to) (I didn't downvote BTW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mutating**

Swift structs are immutable objects meaning that you cannot change its properties within its functions. You need to explicitly mention that you agree to make changes to its properties by adding the `mutating` keyword in the function definition. However this `mutating` jargon is required only for value types in Swift - structs and enums.

```swift
struct MutatingExample {
    var number: Int = 0
    
// Add 'mutating' to resolve the error
    func changeNumber(changedNumber: Int) {
        self.number = changedNumber // Error: Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
    }
}
```

Here is an useful post that might provide you more insights - [What does the Swift 'mutating' keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128666/what-does-the-swift-mutating-keyword-mean)

Reference types such as class do just fine and allow you to change the properties within their functions.

**Override**

Override is a concept used in inheritance. By that we can infer that `override` is applicable to reference types such as *class* and value type(*struct/enums*) are out of question.

As the name implies, we use the keyword to override an existing functionality, typically that of a super class. For example,

```
class Parent {
    func getName() {
        print("Parent")
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    // Add override to resolve error
    func getName() {
        print("Child") // Error: Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword
    }
}
```

Useful link: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/8/3/overriding-methods